# Yii2 backend админка

Tags: yii2

Добрый день. Админка из коробки годиться вообще для реальных проектов? Мне супер-мега выкрутасы в правами доступа и т.д. не нужны. Если да, то как можно ограничить доступ до неё не авторизованным пользователям? Скажем при запросе на (бэкенд) mysite/admin, редиректило на главную страницу сайта (фронтенда).

Comment: "Админка из коробки" - это какая? CRUD он и есть CRUD.

Comment: Да, CRUD. Или админкой называть это нельзя?

Comment: Yii - это не CMS. Там из коробки никаких админок нет.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.
Ограничить доступ к crud можно при помощи фильтра контроля доступа [yii\filters\AccessControl](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/security-authorization.md)

Это самый простой способ закрыть доступ к crub. Но полноценной админкой это назвать нельзя.
Лучше оформить это всё [отдельным модулем](http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/76/seo-service-on-yii2-admin-and-sef) с ограничить доступ с применением [rbac](http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/87/seo-service-on-yii2-adding-rbac).

p.s. Используйте advanced, в этом шаблоне уже есть разделение на админку и пользовательскую части.

Comment: Тут как раз Advanced, есть фронтенд и бэкенд, доступ к методом админки ограничивается, без авторизаци я ничего не могу удалить изменить или добавить, но сам вход в админ панель происходит. Спасибо, почитаю.